# I can't save my system preferences

Tags: spaces, dock, preferences, login

I can't save my dock and spaces setting. Every time I set them (eg. disable spaces), after I reboot/re-login to the system, the dock and spaces settings will revert back to the previous status. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is your computer joined to a network domain with managed preferences?

Comment: Yeah, this sounds exactly like MCX. Did you buy your computer used or new from the Apple store, or is it owned by a company you work for?

Comment: my os version is 10.6.8,and the system preferences works fine a month ago. One day, it sucks.I didn't join any network domain, I think this might caused by some wrong services setting.I shutdown down some system services as so called "optimize tips",maybe that's the problem. I will check them for solution. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. Change the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` to be unlocked (get info, uncheck the locked label) and it will work fine. I don't remember when I locked it, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a terminal command, like `defaults` to change your preferences. For elaboration, you may want to consider telling us exactly what you want.