# Disable Keep In Dock on app move

Tags: macos, dock

I use my dock without any applications ever kept in Dock. Only applications that are open are in the Dock.

When I move an application within the Dock, OS X thinks I want it kept in the Dock.

Does anyone know how to disable this 'keep in Dock on move' feature?

Comment: move an application around… where?

Comment: Within the Dock.

Comment: Yes within the dock. This had been bugging me for a long time because I didn't know why apps seemed to randomly kept in dock. I recently read about the 'keep in dock on move' feature while searching for a fix.

Comment: Here is a link to the informing article that I read: [How can I disable the random/auto keeping of apps in the Dock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17557/how-can-i-disable-the-random-auto-keeping-of-apps-in-the-dock)

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge this is expected behavior. The dock has been doing that (probably) since the 10.0 public beta.

Unfortunately I have seen nothing online, either in App form or a shell or applescript, that would prevent this from happening. Perhaps someone else has run across something that would do this.

Comment: I understand that it is an expected feature but how do we disable it? I remember finding a script that would disable 'Keep in Dock' completely but then you couldn't move apps around within the dock.